# Operar con columnas de un Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe

El origen de esos numeros está en un Dataframe

```
pattern2="(?P<Years>\d+)\syears,\s(?P<Days>\d+)\sdays"
data = {'Age': ['67 years, 295 days','90 years, 247 days']}
n_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
n_ages = n_df['Age'].str.extract(pattern2)
print (n_ages)
```

donde he sobreescrito el string de la columna "Age" por ... un objeto? una serie?
y ahora querria añadir una columna más en la que el total sea

```
Years + Days/365
```

pero si opero con

```
n_ages['Year'] + n_ages['Days'] / 365
```

tengo un error supongo que de conversion de tipos

cual seria la solucion correcta para operar con columnas? como accedo

Gracias otra vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el código que colocas en tu pregunta, lo que contiene tu dataframe`n_ages` es lo siguiente:

```
  Years Days
0    67  295
1    90  247
```

- **Si accedes** a la columna `Years`:

```
print(n_ages['Years'])
```

**Obtienes**:

```
0    67
1    90
Name: Years, dtype: object
```

- Si accedes a su primer elemento:

```
print(n_ages['Years'][0])
```

**Obtienes**:

```
67
```

Ya que es la primera posición.

Lo mismo sucede con la columna `Days`, podrás acceder de esa forma.

- **En cuánto a sumar columnas de un dataframe**:

Podrías usar el método `sum` para sumar las columnas de un dataframe. Si lo usamos:

```
dias_total = n_ages['Days'].sum()
print(dias_total)
```

**E imprimimos el resultado**:

```
295247
```

Vemos que realmente nos está sumando como si fueran `string`. Esto es por el tipo de objeto (`dtype`) que está a object:

```
0    295
1    247
Name: Days, dtype: object
```

Por lo que necesitamos convertir nuestras columnas del dataframe para que sepa que estamos trabajando con datos enteros.

Para hacerlo, podemos usar el método `astype`. Esto no convierte las columnas de forma individual sino todas las columnas del dataframe:

```
n_ages = n_ages.astype(int)
```

Ojo como dato adicional: en caso de querer hacerlo individual porque tengas otras columnas con otro tipo de datos podrías usar `to_numeric` y convertir las columnas específicas que necesites:

```
df["Years"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Years"])
df["Days"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Days"])
```

Una vez que hayas convertido las columnas (vemos que cambia el `dtype`):

```
print(n_ages['Days'])
```

```
0    295
1    247
Name: Days, dtype: int64
```

Ahora si podrás sumar correctamente:

```
n_ages = n_ages.astype(int)
dias_total = n_ages['Days'].sum()
print(dias_total)
```

**Resultado**:

```
542
```

Controlando los tipos de datos y como realizar el cambio, ya podrás hacer las operaciones que necesites.

[dtypes básicos para trabajar con dataframes en python](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes)